# Connect laptop Ethernet with fixed IP directly to Pi, keep Internet up and and running through Wifi?

Tags: ethernet, debian, internet

The laptop runs Debian Jessie. I have set up Ethernet with manual IP to talk to the Pi. Wifi connects via DHCP to my local router and Internet. When Ethernet is unplugged, all is fine, I can browse the Internet through the Wifi. Now when I connect the Ethernet, somehow the Wifi is "overriden", i.e. the system (e.g. browser) only seems to try to connect to the Internet through the Ethernet and doesn't care about the Wifi.

Can I keep browsing the Internet from the laptop with the Wifi while talking to the Pi on Ethernet? Note: I'm not interested in connecting the Pi to the Internet, I simply want to avoid that I cannot browse while connected to the Pi.

Comment: Could you add the output of `route -n` both with and without the Pi connected, please?

Comment: Post the content of your config files. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for what they should contain. NOTE The Pi should have internet access - to set the time, as well as install/update software. It is unclear from your question exactly WHAT you have connected to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can appear when the Wifi router uses the same sub-net as the static IPs configured for ethernet. For instance `192.168.0.*`. A solution can be to move the static IP addresses elsewhere, e.g. `192.168.11.*`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is no longer reproducible (Deiban Buster by now). I can set static IP for ethernet and still use DHCP for the Wifi, and I can then both connect to the Pi and use the Internet.